# Is there any way to put some content over full screen Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, iframe

I have an Iframe displaying an HTML5 output and double clicking it makes it a top-level element. However in the default view, I show an info popup over the Iframe screen from the parent window but it goes invisible when the Iframe becomes the top-level element. so is there any way to show that popup even when the Iframe becomes the top-level element?

This is my React component in which I am trying to display the Iframe

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const CarIframe = () => {
  const [displayBox, setDisplayBox] = useState("none");

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("message", handleMessage);
    };
  }, []);
  const handleMessage = async (event: any) => {
    if (event.data.type === "polyHotspotClicked") {
      handlePolyHotspotClicked();
    }
  };
  async function handlePolyHotspotClicked() {
    setDisplayBox("block");
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <iframe
        src={`/sample/index.html`}
        width={"100%"}
        height={"100%"}
        style={{ margin: "auto" }}
      ></iframe>

      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: "40%",
          top: "36%",
          width: "350px",
          height: "350px",
          backgroundColor: "#E6E5DB",
          display: displayBox,
          borderRadius: "5px",
          boxShadow: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px",
        }}
      >
        <p style={{ margin: "auto", width: "fit-content" }}>POPUP</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CarIframe;
```

so when I double click the Iframe content it goes full screen and makes itself as the top-level element in DOM ( this functionality comes from Iframe content itself ) so that makes the popup in the parent window context invisible and I want to make it interactive and visible even when the Iframe becomes the top-level element. I have managed to open this popup when a certain part (hotspot) in the Iframe is clicked through Javascript's PostMessage API.
I have saved iframe content as a folder in the public directory of react project (you can get that folder [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hTpCR8icsZRI6pFy7ZbRJGOovNawtqkE?usp=sharing)) and this folder is an HTML5 output generated by Object2VR (a program for 360 product photography)
Regards and thanks in advance .

I tried giving a really higher z-index to the popup but it didn't worked as the top-level element has a different stacking context from the normal DOM flow.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as it'll make it a lot easier for us to see what exactly is going on and test any possible solutions.

Comment: Have you tried the `<dialog>` element? It should always be on top even with an iframe.

Comment: If the `iframe` element itself is put into fullscreen mode, then I doubt using a `dialog` element would help either. Not sure if this _can_ be solved, without manipulating the JavaScript that the iframe itself is loading (so that it would make your wrapping div container the actual fullscreen element instead.)